# refactoring the replace method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

```
var x = "mike^+tom&+craig+^tom";

var y = x.replace('^+', '+').replace('&+', '+').replace('+^', '+');

y = mike++tom++craig++tom; // This is the output

expected mike+tom+craig+tom;
```

Instead of chaining the replacing like above, can we do it other way in JavaScript?

Comment: yes, use a regular expression....

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the `replace` method supports a regular expression as input.
This would do what you need:

```
var x = "mike^+tom&+craig+^tom";
x.replace(/\^\+|\&\+|\+\^/g, "+")
```

Result:

```
"mike+tom+craig+tom"
```

Comment: I need output as mike+tom+craig+tom

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace and use regular expressions like this (don't forget the global flag):

```js
var x = "mike^+tom&+craig+^tom";

var y = x.replace(/\^|\&/g, '');

console.log(y)
```